# Using a condensed peek view with 3D Touch

Tags: ios, swift, segue, 3dtouch

I have just implemented the peek and pop feature of 3D Touch into the table view of my app. I am using a different, more condensed view controller for the peek view, and I would like the pop to take the user to the full version of the view (in a similar style to the Instagram app).

I am trying to figure out how I could do this? I can't see how I could do it in the code when I instantiate the peek, so the only thing I could think of is to segue immediately to the full view after the pop?

Anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:**

This is the sort of system I mean:

[image]

Comment: Hi I have a question on your peek and pop. How can you reposition the UItextView /  UILabel  to bottom after you pop your view controller? Thanks...

Comment: @Felix I have separate view controllers for the 'peeked' version and the 'popped' version. The 'popped' version is just the standard view controller that the user would see if they segued as normal.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Solved my puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Maybe do a conditional statement in `- (void)previewingContext:
(id<UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext
     commitViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToCommit` that helps you determine the full screen you want to go to and how it is display. If this conditional statement is met then instantiate the `UIViewController` using `self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier....` and then push to it. Heres my example:

```
- (void)previewingContext(id<UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext
 commitViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToCommit {


    //this check is only for demonstration purposes
    if (viewControllerToCommit) {
        FullViewController * fullVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"fullVC"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:exp animated:YES];

    }
}
```

You can set your storyboard identifier in interface builder:

[image]

Let me know if you need any more help but I would need more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question. Segue directly to the full view. It is not mandatory that you show the `viewControllerToCommit` on pop. You might use that condensed viewController reference only to determine what to pass to your full view. For instance, if it is a detail view, pass the object in your condensed view from which the detail is derived.

```
-(void)previewingContext:(id<UIViewControllerPreviewing>)previewingContext commitViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToCommit
{
   SomeClass *detailObj = viewControllerToCommit.detailObject;
   DetailVCClass *detailViewControllerFull = [[DetailVCClass alloc] initWithObject:detailObj];

   // Present the full VC
   [self presentViewController:detailViewControllerFull animated:YES completion:nil];

   // Alternatively, using Nav controller, you might pop onto the stack
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewControllerFull animated:YES];
}
```

Of course, you are using storyboards so you would adjust accordingly.

The point is, just because they give you the reference to the condensed view that you presented in peek, doesn't mean that this is the view you have to pop. It doesn't help that they named it `viewControllerToCommit`.